# Attack vectors against GPLv3 and how to prevent them?

Tags: gpl-3

One way to get around the GPLv2 is [tivoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivoization). Users get the source code and are allowed to modify it but the hardware rejects any modified software thus denying users some rights that were intended in GPLv2.

What successful attack vectors are there against [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) and how to protect against them?

Definition of attack vector: a way of making GPLv3 software available that does not practically give recipients or users the ability to exercise the [four freedoms](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html#f1) as defined by the FSF.

Comment: Much if this depends on what you consider a possible "attack vector." Some people don't consider tivoization an attack vector against the GPLv2, but a legitimate way to use GPL software. In a similar way, would SaaS be a possible attack vector?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Attack vectors which don't involve hiding the fact that GPLv3 code has been used will be considered a legitimate way to use GPL software by someone. At the very least they will be arguably legal, otherwise they are not effective attack vectors. Yes, I consider [SaaS an attack vector](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/who-does-that-server-really-serve.en.html).

Comment: I basically understand what you're asking, but I think this could benefit substantially from a formal statement of what you consider an "attack vector". Maybe "a way of making GPL software available that does not practically give recipients or users the ability to exercise the four freedoms"? Is Java-Trap-style free code written for a proprietary environment an attack vector?

Comment: @apsillers Suggestion for improvement incorporated. Thanks.

Comment: Easiest way to use GPLv3 stuff and not have to distribute source for it would be to use it to create a SaaS platform of some type.  Which is why the AGPL exists...

Comment: The phrasing "attack vectors" is too misleading. It seems you mean an attack against the free software philosophy, but attack vector usually implies security issues.

Comment: @Brandin Indeed, I mean an attack against the free software filosophy. As for security... a GPL which allows breachs of the four freedoms would be considered as an insecure license from such point of view. Though maybe that is streching things a bit too much. What phrasing do you suggest?

Comment: @ivanivan GPLv3 only applies when the source is being conveyed, and per the GPLv3 definition of "convey", SaaS is not a conveyance since you can't make a copy of the source or the binary. Thus SaaS is an allowed usage, not an attack vector.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy - read the OPs comment to Brandin - avoiding having to distribute source by using SaaS certainly seems like an "attack of the philosophy of Free software" - if it weren't we wouldn've have the AGPL

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos "Ways of undermining/attacking/violating the spirit of the GPLv3 and how to prevent them." (Pick the appropriate word you want). Editorially speaking there should be no question mark at the end of this title. It is a question statement like "how to do blah", it is not an interrogative question such as "how do I do blah?"